# How to retrieve a constraint name in an existing database

Tags: django, django-models

In a migration, I want to remove an index from a table (before adding a new one).

The model doesn't do anything special before the migration. It's using the default `Autofield` from django.

I can do that with a `RunSQL` like this:

```
ALTER TABLE model DROP CONSTRAINT model_pkey
```

But it turns out that the name of the constraint (for the primary key) is not always the same, because it used to be named differently in the past.

So I'm looking for a way to retrieve the name of constraint, even if it's not the default one.

Comment: Is this index created using Django migrations or added manually by you in database shell (psql for example)?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-indexes.html

Comment: @PTomasz the index was first added by django migrations, if I'm understanding properly.

Comment: @AlexisMétaireau could you edit your question to include your model?

Comment: @PTomasz The model doesn't do anything special, it's using an autofield by default by Django. I've updated my question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with :

```
DO $$
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE model DROP CONSTRAINT ' || (
    SELECT indexname 
    FROM pg_indexes 
    WHERE tablename = 'model' AND indexname LIKE '%pkey'
);
END $$;
```